# Failed to access MongoDB Atlas cluster from eks pod with peering connection setup

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, mongodb-atlas, aws-vpc-peering

Getting error:

> socket timeout calling ismaster on
> 'custer-name-shard-00-00.somekey.mongodb.net:27017'

When trying to access MongoDB Atlas cluster from a pod deployed on AWS EKS.
Whereas I get successful connection when adding 0.0.0.0/0 to MongoDB Atlas IP Access list, so I thing request is not routed through peering connection.

Please could you explain me how to ensure appropriate routing though MongoDB Altas VPC peering connection.

I exposed MongoDB connection test pod using a LoadBalancer Service which allow to enter MongoDB cluster settings.

I tried dnsPolicy: "ClusterFirstWithHostNet" and dnsPolicy: "Default" in deployment yml (using Helm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to make my vpc peering functional by relying on the official documentation available on the following links:

- [Set up a Network Peering Connection](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/)
- [Automating MongoDB Atlas VPC Peering with Terraform](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/automating-mongodb-atlas-vpc-peering-with-terraform)